# Magento 1.9.2 exception.log throwing up erros continously

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, exception

Sites been slow and many people are unable to access to the site. The exception.logs been throwing up an an invalid block error and i cant find where this error is cropping up from. The error is mainly in the PRODUCT.INFO.UPSELL block and i tried searching through the layout xml files but i couldnt find anything. Can someone help please.

The error is as follows

```
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /home/*******/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'product.info.up...')
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'product.info.up...')
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(28, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/home/*******/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
/home/*******/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/home/*******/p
```

I tried the following solution, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217215/magento-illegal-block-type
which says - It looks like something to do with your upsell block on the product view page. Check your template files (catalog.xml) and ensure you have a block type set for the block definition with name product.info.upsell. To establish if this is where you error originates you could comment out the line getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?> in view.phtml and the xml definitions for the block mentioned above.

So i went to the following destination on my magento installation -

/home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/megatron/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

and applied the above mentioned solution but still no success

Comment: Check first byte receive time    By inspect in browser and which part time taking so much time clear cache  and reindex

Comment: Hey @lalitmohan thanks for replying. Will do that, but my main problem is the exception.log errors thats showing up

Comment: As per your error when Magento is loading the layout update xml files, and using them to create the blocks which will render the HTML for the page.   Problem with addBlock , createBlock  dispatch may be missing some syntax

Comment: Check catalog.xml for layout syntax may be miss block type ,name or use <block type=""> instead of <reference name ="">

Comment: @lalitmohan already tried that still no success

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit 
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495)`
 and logging the block type that it's rendering. You can then try to figure out where this block is being inserted - it can be added from a layout xml file or it can be generated from php code.

However, unless your log file is huge, this probably isn't the cause for performance degradation. It's not ok to have this, but things should work fine with a bug like this.

PS - edit that file temporary, on a dev or stage env, not live

Comment: not much of success yet. Log file is growing like 1 mb every day. I get an exception every moment someones on the site.

Comment: does it happen anywhere or a specific page, like product page, category page, etc?

Comment: happens every 2 minutes or so. My reading is that it happens when someone logs on to the product page on the site.

Comment: i rechecked the exception trail, and it looks like the upsell block is introduced without a type. do you use any extensions for automatic upsell/related products? have you checked all layout xmls for typos? try linting them. looks like the error is coming from the xml's. ultimately, it could be from layout updates (per product), but it doesn't look like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check the layout xmls. can you advice me what i should be looking for ?

Comment: Anything that could add that block... usually a direct reference. Try look for that name you see in the trace, maybe the block node is missing a type attribute

Comment: Do you think moving to magento 1.9.3 would be of any help?

Comment: For security reasons you should upgrade. But it won't solve this issue, unless someone edited core files...